# Question about Russell paradox and hierarchy process Terence Tao

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I wanted to ask if someone can give me more information that Terence is talking about in his book? I am presenting couple of his ideas in school that I am co-teaching. I am interested in more information about this hierarchy business.

[image]

Comment: What sort of additional information do you want?

Comment: I am interested in more information about this hierarchy business.

Comment: This is really just Tao's way of explaining the [axiom of regularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Axiom_of_regularity). If you can't be more specific, I can't do much more than to point you to the wikipedia page.

Comment: I didn't know there is a wikipedia page for this thank you !